# Spark SQL Correlated column is not allowed in predicate

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, correlated-subquery

I have to join 2 tables in Spark such that the value of a column in first table is within the range of the columns in second table. There is no joining column between the two table hence I can not use the normal join SQL. I am using the below query:

```
select t.*, (select MAX(p.grade) from table1 p where 
p.marks_lower_bound <= ROUND(t.marks) and 
p.marks_upper_bound >= ROUND(t.marks)) from table2 t;
```

So based on the marks in table2 I want to find the grade that is stored in table1 with the marks ranges. I am receiving the below error:

```
AnalysisException: Correlated column is not allowed in predicate
```

Any idea how to resolve this is Spark SQL? I have tried this query in MySQL and it is working fine there, but it is failing in Spark SQL. Note that `table1` and `table2` are the temp tables created from other Spark APIs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Correlated columns are not allowed with non-equality predicates ->[SPARK-36114](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-36114).

You can use "normal" join though. Just note that you can't have `*` in `group by`, so you need to provide column list explicitly. Or maybe you don't need grouping at all (if ranges are not overlapping).

```sql
select t.col1, t.col2, max(p.grade)
  from table2 t
  left join table1 p on (p.marks_lower_bound <= round(t.marks)
                     and p.marks_upper_bound >= round(t.marks))
 group by t.col1, t.col2;
```